# Redirect a PDF referencing old 2007 site

Tags: 2010, 2007, iis, redirect

We have a SharePoint 2010 site that has numerous documents migrated over from our old SharePoint 2007 site.  These documents that were migrated to 2010 (PDFs) have links in them that reference old documents on our 2007 site.

We would like to capture these requests on the 2007 server and redirect them to a search page on our new 2010 farm.  Because of this, we would like to capture the requested URL, capture the filename (asdf.pdf) and input that as the search term after the redirect to the 2010 search page occurrs.

I have tried utilizing various methods (ASP, Javascript, IIS) but nothing seems to be working.  Either the redirect doesn't occurr, or we lose access to the requested URL after the referral.  How can this be accomplished?  Keep in mind we do not have access to URL Rewrite on the 2007 server as we are running Windows Server 2003 on it and would very much not like to devote resources to upgrading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used IIRF( https://iirf.codeplex.com/) URL rewrite tool on my 2003 servers. It works on 32bit and 64bit systems and had no problems so far...